# Find the lowest value in dict

Tags: python

I want to find the lowest value in dict, such as:

```
chars_dict = {}
chars_dict[0] = {'hp':750}
chars_dict[1] = {'hp':1000}
chars_dict[2] = {'hp':500}
```

and get 2

Comment: The code does not yet compile. Can you edit it?

Comment: If the keys are going to be integers from `0` to `n`, you should probably use a `list`.

Comment: Also we are not a coding service.

Comment: sry edited, list is not an option, but anyway thank for attention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one-line answer using the `min` function with personalized `key` would be

```
min(chars_dict, key=lambda(item): chars_dict[item]['hp'])
```

I think it's the best solution, because you want to find the element with the lowest `'hp'`.

Also, if you're using dictionaries as containers with constant keys, it may be better to use custom classes. And if the keys in the dict are ascending by 1, you may as well use a list.

Comment: Perfectly! This solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
hp_list = [750, 1000, 500]


print(min(hp_list))
print('at position ', hp_list.index(min(hp_list)))
```

You're are approaching the problem the wrong way and also repeating yourself, if all the values in the dictionary are going to be `'hp'` better create a list and store all hp in there.